# Read only a section of tif using R

Tags: r, raster, tiff

I have a large tif file which does not fit in memory. I'm wondering whether if I can read in just a section of this tif file based on an extent.

I'm using R and so far have not been able to find a solution. I know that it can be done using C#, so I guess there should be a way in R.

Thanks!

Comment: reduce resolution  and try

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [rtiff](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/rtiff/versions/1.4.5) package. The `readTiff` function can reduce image size.

Answer (score 1):

Odds are if you're working with rasters in R, you're using the `raster` package.

Here's how you can do it:

```
library(raster)

# testraster

r <- raster(system.file("external/test.grd", package="raster"))

# not in memory

inMemory(r)
# [1] FALSE
```

If we look at the raster object, we can see that the raster has 115 rows and 80 columns:

```
r
# class       : RasterLayer 
# dimensions  : 115, 80, 9200  (nrow, ncol, ncell)
# resolution  : 40, 40  (x, y)
# extent      : 178400, 181600, 329400, 334000  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
# coord. ref. : +init=epsg:28992 +towgs84=565.237,50.0087,465.658,-0.406857,0.350733,-1.87035,4.0812 +proj=sterea +lat_0=52.15616055555555 +lon_0=5.38763888888889 +k=0.9999079 +x_0=155000 +y_0=463000 +ellps=bessel +units=m +no_defs 
# data source : /usr/local/lib/R/site-library/raster/external/test.grd 
# names       : test 
# values      : 128.434, 1805.78  (min, max)
```

So let's load a 10 x 10 block from the center:

```
arr <- getValuesBlock(r,row=58,nrows=10,col=40, ncols=10,format='matrix')
```

This will return a matrix, which you can further process, plot, ... etc.

```
plot(raster(arr))
```

[image]